# configuration is still incorrect.do you want to edit it again?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, google-places-api, genymotion

i'm using android studio for a few days ..... but the problem is 
when i want to run an android app(exiting project)
on genymotion emulator (already installed and works normal)

this message appears

[image]

so i want a solution for this problem.

Comment: Did you see the error message in the bottom margin of the window: "AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag"

Comment: yes i see this error message "AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag"

Comment: @luke.....and what does it tell you if you read this error message about the manifest? ;)

Comment: look my friend i'm the first time using this android studio so i installed it normal and then install genymotion emulator and match it with android studio and works nomally finally when i import an existing project and i want to run it using geny motion i found that (look at this image bellow )

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fEaPBpm.png

Comment: was it an eclipse project?

Comment: so i decide to edit configuration so i make <Edit configuration> android app and that's what happen (look at this image) http://i.imgur.com/vWP0BdJ.png ,, when i click run this error msg take place.

Comment: yes i think is eclipse but i think also work on android project